# How to construct a numpy array of numbers of powers of 2 more elegantly?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, numpy-ndarray

I would like to figure out how i can create this array without putting every single value in per hand.

Is there a way how i can use the information that every value is the doubled value of its predecessor, except for the first?

My Code is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

Matrix = np.array([1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]).reshape (3,3)

print(Matrix)
```

Comment: Maybe not more elegant, but a bitshift works in this case: `np.left_shift(1,np.arange(9)).reshape(3,3)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), and take advantage of the fact that they are powers of `2`:

```
2**np.arange(9).reshape(-1, 3)

array([[  1,   2,   4],
       [  8,  16,  32],
       [ 64, 128, 256]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
var myRandomArray = [1];
var i = 1;
var num = 1;
while (i < 9) {
  myRandomArray.push(num = num * 2);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

This is written in JavaScript. For Python, just switch what you need around, the main idea is still there. I believe in Python, it is append instead of push.

Comment: OP is looking for a python solution, as clear with the tags of the question

Comment: gave him a javascript solution, the main idea is the solution of the problem as a python programmer will know what the syntax is

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.vander`:

```
np.vander([2], 9, True).reshape(3, 3)
# array([[  1,   2,   4],
#        [  8,  16,  32],
#        [ 64, 128, 256]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jury-rigged solution:

```
In [10]: total_num = 9 

In [11]: np.array([2**n for n in range(0, total_num)]).reshape(3, -1) 
Out[11]: 
array([[  1,   2,   4],
       [  8,  16,  32],
       [ 64, 128, 256]])
```